# Managing Delays in an android app

Tags: android, autocomplete

Hey guys, i would like to know how to manage delays in an android application, for example, I have an overridden method onTextChanged(). In relation to that I want to set a delay like .5 seconds in order to finalized what the user is typing in my autocomplete textbox. If the user hangs/stop typing in .5 sec, i wanted a certain method or implementation to execute in my code(i.e. my own filtering scheme/logic in my autocomplete textbox, just to lessen resource usage within my app, thanks).

Here's my sample code:

```
protected AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteView;
protected AutoCompleteAdapter suggsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);    

    autoCompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);  

    TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

//here inside this overridden method, I wanted to create a delay in order to lessen the
//use of resources.

            String enteredText = autoCompleteView.getText().toString();             
            refreshList(enteredText);

        }
    };        


    autoCompleteView.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);

}
```

and for example, the user typed "Lond"(for String like "London") with each letter typed less than .5 sec, I want all the previous onTextChanged() method called(method call in typing "L", "o" and "n") to be disregarded and only the onTextChanged() when the last letter was typed would be granted for execution.

How would I do that, please help me:(.

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840390/4685284

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `Handler` subclass and call `Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed()` or `Handler.sendMessageDelayed()` method when `onTextChanged()` is triggered. And you can remove messages from the message queue using `Handler.removeMessages()`. You should process messages in `Handler.handleMessage()` method. So your `onTextChanged()` method will be something like:

```
mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, 500);
```

**EDIT**: Here's an example of code. I haven't tested it yet, so I'm not sure it works.

```
private static final int AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY = 500;
private static final int MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED) {
            String enteredText = (String)msg.obj;
            refreshList(enteredText);
        }
    }
};

// ... your code here

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String enteredText = autoCompleteView.getText().toString();             
    mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);
    final Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, enteredText);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY);
}
```

Comment: any specifics?, I am new to android development. so any particular code implementation in my code would be greatly appreciated. hehe:D

Comment: I added some implementation details to the answer.

Comment: So far it works, but it comes with more issues when using Handler like, unusual behavior of my adapter. :( maybe using Handler is good for back-end threading not in the UI. hehe :)

Comment: No, it can be used in the UI. For example, `AsyncTask` is based on `Handler`. I think the reason of the problem  with your adapter is not in `Handler`.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing Running code for autocomplete.

First **onTextChanged** will be called.

```
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           String newText = s.toString();
           if(!newText.trim().equals(""))
            Autocompletes_Timer(newText);
       }
```

now we need a Handler.

```
Hander handler = new Handler();
private void Autocompletes_Timer(final String newText) {

    // new text will be here. so if you type fast within 1 sec.
    // handler will be remover each time so that handler post delay also be remove.
    if(handler!= null)
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    // new text will be in runnable with 1 sec delay. 
    handler.postDelayed(runnable(newText), 1000);
}

   // it will be start work after 1 sec.
   // if you stop the typing then it will complete work like as sending data at server.
   // if you continue typing , it will not complete work and each type will be removeCallbackAndMessage.
    private Runnable runnable(final String newText) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("Autocompleted", newText);

            // call AysncTask here  
        }

    };
    return runnable;
}
```

just copy and paste my code. It should be fix your problem . Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

use a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
protected AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteView;
protected AutoCompleteAdapter suggsAdapter;

String TAG = "Timer";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);    

    autoCompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);  

    TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(500,100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.d(TAG, "addressTextWatcher.countDownTimer.onTick() -> Tick: " + millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "addressTextWatcher.countDownTimer.onTick() -> Finish");

                String enteredText = autoCompleteView.getText().toString();             
                refreshList(enteredText);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();

            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    };        


    autoCompleteView.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);

}
```