# How to set AutocompleteTextView to perform only one filter search at a time and set a delay before starting the filtering?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, filter, autocompletetextview

I have this question related the AutocompleteTextView. Basically I have implemented a custom adapter with a custom Filter which filters a list of custom objects and all is working fine except that when I type in a fast way in the autocompleteTextView seems like a queue of worker filter threads starts and the typing and filtering itself becomes really slow. How can I set only ONE filter at a time based on the latest input of the user (thus cancel the previous filter thread if it actually runs) and set a small delay before starting the filtering so when the user types fast the autocomplete doesn't slow???

Thanks!

EDIT: I have this custom adapter with a Filter implementation:

```
public class MunicipalitySearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Municipality> {

private ArrayList<Municipality> municipalities;
private ArrayList<Municipality> allMunicipalities;
private ArrayList<Municipality> suggestedMunicipalities;

private List<Trieable> triableList;

private Trie municipalityTrie;

private int viewResourceId;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MunicipalitySearchAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId, ArrayList<Municipality> municipalities) {
    super(context, viewResourceId, municipalities);
    this.municipalities = municipalities;
    this.allMunicipalities = (ArrayList<Municipality>) this.municipalities.clone();
    this.suggestedMunicipalities = new ArrayList<Municipality>();
    this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    this.triableList = new ArrayList<Trieable>();
    for (Municipality mun : allMunicipalities) {
        triableList.add(mun);
    }
    municipalityTrie = new Trie(triableList, Locale.ITALY);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(this.viewResourceId, null);
    }
    Municipality municipality = municipalities.get(position);
    if (municipality != null) {
        TextView munNameTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView proSignTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sign);
        TextView regNameTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.regionName);

        if (munNameTxtView != null) {
            munNameTxtView.setText(municipality.getName());
        }
        if (proSignTxtView != null) {
            proSignTxtView.setText(municipality.getProvinceSign());
        }
        if (regNameTxtView != null) {
            regNameTxtView.setText(municipality.getRegionName());
        }
    }
    return v;
}

@Override 
public Filter getFilter() {
    return municipalityFilter;
}

Filter municipalityFilter = new Filter() {      
    CharSequence filterConstraint;
    @Override
    public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        String str = ((Municipality) (resultValue)).getName();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterRes = new FilterResults();
        synchronized (filterRes) {
            if (this.filterConstraint == null) {
                this.filterConstraint = constraint;
            }

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filterRes.values = allMunicipalities;
                filterRes.count = allMunicipalities.size();
            }

            else {
                String constraintString = constraint.toString().trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ITALY);
                suggestedMunicipalities.clear();

                List<Integer> wordsIndexesList = municipalityTrie.getWordsIndexes(municipalityTrie.getRootVertex(), constraintString);
                for (int index : wordsIndexesList) {
                    suggestedMunicipalities.add(allMunicipalities.get(index));
                }

                List<Integer> prefixesIndexesList = municipalityTrie.getPrefixesIndexes(municipalityTrie.getRootVertex(), constraintString);
                for (int index : prefixesIndexesList) {
                    suggestedMunicipalities.add(allMunicipalities.get(index));
                }

                filterRes.values = suggestedMunicipalities;
                filterRes.count = suggestedMunicipalities.size();                   
            }
        }

        return filterRes;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            synchronized (results) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<Municipality> filteredMunicipalities = (ArrayList<Municipality>) results.values;
                ArrayList<Municipality> supportMunicipalitiesList = new ArrayList<Municipality>();

                clear();
                for (Municipality mun : filteredMunicipalities) {
                    supportMunicipalitiesList.add(mun);
                }
                Iterator<Municipality> municipalityIterator = supportMunicipalitiesList.iterator();
                while (municipalityIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Municipality municipality = municipalityIterator.next();
                    add(municipality);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }           
    }
};
}
```

How can I make a Loader manage this filter worker thread?

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840390/4685284

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to use Loader. On textinput change restart the loader to search for the current text. So if there is a loder with same Id is already running it will be restarted. This will make sure you will get the result of last input . I am using this approach in one of my app in play store.

```
   getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, callback);
 // 0 - I'd
// pass the input text through bundle
// callback - loader callback
```

Note : you can call restart for the first search itself, it will be created if not exist.

Check this link if your not aware of loader 
   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Thanks for the response I have read the Loader guide you posted. Sorry, I would like to ask you some questions about this interesting topic. "So if there is a loader with same Id is already running it will be restarted" means the previous loader with the same ID will be destroyed and another Loader with the same ID will be created (so the onCreateLoader() will be called)? And why are you passing a bundle? The Callback could be a filter() call of the Filter class???

Comment: its not completely recreating the loader, the current running work will be stopped and new work will be started.  bundle is just to pass data to the callback, it can be null.

Comment: So if I have a filter(Charset s), could I do something like: 

getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s)); ? So the Loader will run the filtering?

Comment: No , 3rd argument is loader callback to respond back the response from loader.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. How can I integrate this Loader call in my filter method (I post my code in the EDIT label).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html. check this, I t has clear explanation