# autocompletetextview with retrofit

Tags: android

I am using an implementation of `AutoCompleteTextView` in which suggestions are fetched from webapi and displayed based on user input. I am using retrofit client for making network connection.i have two doubts.

1) I don't want request to be sent for every character typed. It should send request only if user hold for 5 seconds. How can I implement in my `AutoCompleteTextView` implementation.

2) I am using observable for response, if two requests are sent from client one after another, how observable handle responses so that only last response is handled at client.

I could not post my code now, however in case of problem i will post it.

Answer (score 0):

For waiting to send a request, you can use a TextWatcher's onTextChanged method.

Every time the text is changed, you can update a variable such as timePressed with the system method System.currentTimeMillis. After updating, you can check to see if the current system time is more than a certain amount of time (such as 5000ms) since the previous time the text was changed. If so, call the method which sends out your API request.

See the following resources for more guidance:

[TextWatcher onTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int))

[currentTimeMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

[Similar Question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761113/autocompletion-delay)

Comment: If i use your approach,when user types a character ,variable will store current time and check that currenttime-timepressed is not more than 5000ms so it will not send request but how it will automatically send request after 5000ms because checking condition is not in loop.

Comment: The onTextChanged method is called every single time the text changes (i.e. user enters or deletes a character) - if it has been over 5 seconds since the user last changed the text then you should call the method which sends your API request.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
// Setup The Category Autocomplete

    private void setupCategoryAutocomplete() {

        Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitClientLaravel.getInstance()
                                                     .videosGetApi()
                                                     .getCategories();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call,
                                   Response<JsonObject> response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                    // Check If User Array Has Anything
                    JSONArray returnArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("video_categories");
                    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

                    if (!returnArray.isNull(0)) {

                        for (int l = 0; l < returnArray.length(); l++) {
                            if (returnArray.length() > 0) {

                                // Get The Json Object
                                JSONObject returnJSONObject = returnArray.getJSONObject(l);

                                // Get Details
                                String category = returnJSONObject.optString("category");
                                str.add(category);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                                                                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                                             str.toArray(new String[]{}));
                    atvCategory.setAdapter(adapter1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call,
                                  Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```